# Get direction through Map doesn't work with iOS 7

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, ios7, mkannotationview

I calling this method to direct the user on Apple Map. It was working fine with iOS 6 but now it is not working with iOS 7. So please where it would be the issue?

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

lat1 = [[view annotation]coordinate].latitude;
lon1 = [[view annotation]coordinate].longitude;

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", lat1,lon1,lat,lon];    

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
-(void)direct:(id)sender{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = 40.896056;
coordinate.longitude = 29.217947;

MKPlacemark *mPlacemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:mPlacemark];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey  : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the coordinate twice?

Comment: @rckoenes even if I set one coordinate it is not responding. I have edited the code. I just want to set the direction from my location to that coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`MKPlacemark`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on iOS 6 and above.

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:[view annotation]coordinate]] addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey  : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];
```

Comment: I am getting an issue `[view annotation]coordinate]` Could you please explain more?

Comment: If you can post more about the issue I might be able to help.